# how do I find the smallest natural number that is greater than or equal to A?

Tags: javascript

The numbers A and B are given to find the smallest natural number obtained from the transitions of the digits B that is greater than or equal to A
For example
A = 3075, B = 6604 // output 4066

```
eaxmple
A = 6604, B = 3012 // output 0

example
A = 101, B = 105 // output 105
```

This is my code

```js
function solution([A, B]) {
  for (let i = 0; i < B; i++) {
    if (i >= A) {
      B = B.toString().split("")
      let b = B.map(i => Number(i));
      for (let k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
        if (i.includes(b[k])) {
          return i
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0
}
console.log(solution([3075, 6604]))
```

Comment: could you better explain what you are trying to do? what does transition mean?

Comment: I want to change the places of the digits of B and get the smallest number that is equal to or equal to A.

Comment: do a and b always have the same number of digits?

Comment: no, they can have different values

Comment: What is your question? Your code snippet is giving me an error "i.includes is not a function", which seems self-explanatory.